# Dot product of vector and normal

Tags: vector-analysis

Here is the problem:

"A plane, whose normal (directed away from the origin) is at an angle α to the z axis, and
whose perpendicular distance to the origin is a, is intersected by the sphere $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$
along
the circle C. The direction of C is positive relative the outward normal of the sphere on the part of
the sphere with the greater surface area. Calculate the integral.

$$\oint_c \bar{A} • d\bar r$$

Where $A = (3xz + a(z + x))\bar x+ (3xz + a(z-x))\bar y + (3xy + a(x+y))\bar z$ "

I know that for this we use stokes theorem so we get:

$$\nabla \times \bar A = -2a \bar z$$

So we get
$$\oint_c \bar{A} • d\bar r = \iint \nabla \times \bar A • d\bar S =  \iint -2a \bar z•\hat n dS  $$

So in the solution is says
$$ \bar z•\hat n =-cos\alpha  $$

So if I understood this part I would be able come to the solution my self.
Lets say we instead have
$$ \bar y •\hat n = ? $$
$$ \bar x •\hat n = ? $$
What would we get instead of questionmark?

I am simply not understanding the dot product of the vector with the normal. I wish someone can explain this to me so that I may understand it.

Comment: You know the angle of the normal vector with $z-$axis. That is why you do $\hat{n} \cdot \hat{k}$. Also given that the curl of the vector field is $-2a\hat{k}$, why would you do $\hat{j} \cdot \hat{n}$?

Comment: Oh,yea I know. I am just curious what those two hypothetical dot products would yield.

Comment: You cannot. You also need to know the angle that the projection of the vector in $XY$ plane makes with $x-$axis or $y-$axis (azimuthal angle). Take an example, this vector could be in $XZ$ plane and make an angle of $\alpha$ with $z-$axis. Then $\hat{j} \cdot \hat{n} = 0$ or this vector could be in $YZ$ plane and make an angle of $\alpha$ with $z-$axis. Then $\hat{i} \cdot \hat{n} = 0$.

Comment: Well let us say that the rotation returns i j k vector. I guess what I am asking is, if it returns i vector, what would it be?